# I am getting this result (for i, label in enumerate(train_paths): NameError: name 'train_paths' is not defined Process finished with exit code 1)

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

dataset pre-processing

```
train_path = 'datasets/train'
test_path = 'datasets/test'
train_labels = os.listdir(train_path)
test_labels = os.listdir(test_path)
```

tunable parameters

```
image_size = (256, 256)
num_train_images = 10000
num_test_images = 34
num_channels = 3

# train_x dimension = {(256*256*3), 10000}
# train_y dimension = {1, 10000}
# test_x dimension  = {(256*256*3), 34}
# test_y dimension  = {1, 34}
train_x = np.stack(((image_size[0]*image_size[1]*num_channels), num_train_images))
train_y = np.stack((1, num_train_images))
test_x = np.stack(((image_size[0]*image_size[1]*num_channels), num_test_images))
test_y = np.stack((1, num_test_images))
```

train dataset

```
count = 0
num_label = 0
for i, label in enumerate(train_paths):
    cur_path = train_path + "//" + label
    for image_path in glob.glob(cur_path + "/*.jpg"):
        img = image_size.load_img(train_path, target_size=image_size)
        x = image_size.img_to_array(img)
        x = x.flatten()
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        train_x[:, count] = x
        train_y[:, count] = num_label
        count += 1
        num_label += 1
```

test dataset

```
count = 0
num_label = 0
for i, label in enumerate(test_labels):
    cur_path = test_path + "//" + label
    for image_path in glob.glob(cur_path + "/*.jpg"):
        img = image_size.load_img(test_path, target_size=image_size)
        x = image_size.img_to_array(img)
        x = x.flatten()
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        test_x[:, count] = x
        test_y[:, count] = num_label
        count += 1
        num_label += 1
```

standardization

```
train_x = train_x / 255.
test_x = test_x / 255.
print("train_labels: " + str(train_labels))
print("train_x shape:" + str(train_x.shape))
print("train_y shape:" + str(train_y.shape))
print("test_x shape :" + str(test_x.shape))
print("test_y shape :" + str(test_y.shape))
```

save using h5py

```
h5_train = h5py.File('train_x.h5', 'w')
h5_train.create_dataset("data_train", data=np.array(train_x))
h5_train.close()

h5_test = h5py.File('test_x.h5', 'w')
h5_test.create_dataset("data_test", data=np.array(test_x))
h5_test.close()
```

**Here is the result i got back**

for i, label in enumerate(train_paths):
NameError: name 'train_paths' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: As the exception states, you did not assign any value into `train_paths`...

Comment: i assigned it at the beginning of the code

Comment: It does not appear in the code you show here, and Python shows you didn't. I believe Python.

Comment: Thinking about it, you are probably running a notebook, and didn't run some top cell.

Comment: import numpy as np
import os
import h5py
import glob

i ran those first

Comment: yes it is python

Comment: I am basically trying to encode image datasets into text

Comment: The problem is clear. `train_paths` is not defined.